# What are the safest ways to identify an external Microsoft login using a ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a web application that uses Microsoft accounts to sign in. How can I safely and reliably grant external users access to this application by email address without requiring that I train users on Azure administration or have to implement some approval mechanism via API?

I believe that it is dangerous to use the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.Name, which returns an email address. It uses the "preferred_username" claim behind the scenes, which along with the "email" claim are documented to not be a safe and reliable way to identify a user, so I assume that's user configurable and thus can be spoofed by a creative user.

It seems like if the user knows the email address or account name that they use to sign into their Microsoft account, that should be enough to authorize that user to access the application without requiring that they go through an additional step of verifying an email which I trust they use to sign in, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process of creating and granting the external users access to the application:

[image]

Please go this document for more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We ended up going with a unique PIN for each user. On initial sign-in, we display the information from their Microsoft account and ask them to verify their PIN. Once the user verifies, we track the UID internally.